# How do I get the string length of the stringValue of an NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is probably a naive question but, how do I get the length of the `stringValue` of an `NSTextField`? I tried

```
int len = strlen((char *)[textField stringValue]);
```

where `textField` is an `NSTextField` but it always returns 6 (size of a pointer?). Besides I am sure that there is a more Objective-C way to do what I am after.

Comment: When you do use `strlen` (i.e., on a C string), you should use the `size_t` type to hold its return value. At the very least, this is an unsigned type, whereas `int` (not otherwise qualified) is signed. This becomes important when the return value is out of the positive range of the signed type, which will put it in the negative range and make your comparison expressions fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [NSString documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
NSUInteger length = [[textField stringValue] length];
```

The crucial thing to realize here is that an NSString is not a char*. To get a real C-style char*, you need to do something like:

```
const char* ptr = [[textField stringValue]
    cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
```

Updated to use default encoding instead of assuming ASCII.

Comment: just nitpicking, but using NSASCIIStringEncoding is more dangerous than simply passing a zero, which will give you the default encoding.
regardless, +1

Comment: Good point. I didn't find the 0 thing documented anywhere, so I went the explicit route.

Answer (score 2):

stringValue is NSString instance.
You may use the next code:

```
NSUInteger len = [[textField stringValue] length];
```